# Are Team Foundation Server (on-premises version) updates cumulative?

Tags: team-foundation-server

When installing an update to Microsoft Team Foundation Server, are the updates cumulative? For example, my currently installed version is TFS 2015 RTM. There are currently 3 updates that have been released after RTM (Update 1, Update 2, and Update 3). Can I just install Update 3 or do I have to install all previous updates in order?

I'm not seeing this addressed on the [release page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2015-update3-vs).

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are, but you cant go from any version to any other. If, for example, you are coming from TFS 2010 (or prior) you will need to stage your upgrade through TFS 2013.5.

[image: TFS Upgrade Matrix]

Comment: I was wondering more at the service pack level (or "update" as they're called for TFS) rather than major versions (_e.g._, going from _RTM_ directly to _Update3_ without first installing _Update1_ and _Update2_). But I assume that's covered by the opening statement "Yes they are."

Comment: Correct, unless you have a much older version of TFS. 2015.X = any version of 2015.